# Walkers Join! - Alan Walker's logo

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

You might know Alan Walker from his ever popular song Faded. Now his "followers" are called Walkers and they have a logo, here is a simplified version:

```
\\
 \\              //\\  
  \\            //  \\            //
   \\          //    \\          //
    \\        //      \\        //
     \\      //        \\      //
      \\    //          \\    //
       \\  //    //\\    \\  //
        \\//    //  \\    \\//
         //    //    \\    \\
        //\\  //      \\  //\\
           \\//        \\//  \\
                              \\
```

The goal of this challenge is to print this logo.

**RULES:**

1. If you return a list of strings from a function as per meta standards, please provide a footer that prints it to the screen.
2. All characters of the above logo have to be there. No shortcuts!
3. Shortest number of bytes wins!

Comment: can there be extra spaces at the end of each line (as they don't change how the output looks)? Can there be leading/appending newlines?

Comment: @dzaima, yes you can.

Comment: +1 for Alan Walker!!

Comment: Walkers Join! - W41k3r 28881

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
Ｆ²«Ｊι⁰↙χ↖↖⁵↙↙⁵↖↖²Ｐ↖χ↙↗χ↘↘¹²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0hToZqL06s0tyAkXyNTR8FA05qLM6AoM69Ew8olvzzPJzWtREfBECzsm1@WqmEVWgASQ1IGEdBRMEWogenEapgpEWYZgdWU5pRkFqBKILsEiy2hBUGZ6RlY1IGF0ZwDUwqyrPb///@6Zf91i3MA) Link is to verbose version of code. Sadly `Copy` doesn't do what I want in this case, so I have to loop instead. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²«Ｊι⁰
```

Draw everything twice, but with the cursor starting one character to the right the second time.

```
   ↙χ↖↖⁵↙↙⁵↖↖²Ｐ↖χ
```

Draw the main W from right to left, but leave the cursor near the inverted V.

```
   ↙↗χ↘↘¹²
```

Draw the inverted V.

Comment: You "only" beat the naive solutions by 20 bytes :P

Comment: @StepHen A 46% saving isn't bad given the overhead of setting a loop up in the first place...

Comment: Is mirroring just not shorter for this?

Comment: @StepHen Fixing up the asymmetry costs too much. Best I could do was 35 bytes: `Ｆ²«Ｊι⁰↘χ↗↗⁵Ｍ⁵↑←↙χ»‖Ｍ↥\\¶ \\Ｆ²«Ｊι⁰↖³`.

Answer (score 13):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>172</s> 139 bytes

```js
let f =

_=>`1
3s1
5o5o
7k9k
9gdg
bchc
d8l8
f48194
h08590
i899
g14d41
n0h05
1p`.replace(/.p?/g,n=>' '.repeat((n=parseInt(n,36))/2)+(c='/\\'[n&1])+c)

O.innerText = f()
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

#### How?

The logo basically consists of groups of spaces followed by either `//` or `\\` and line feeds.

Spaces and ending patterns are encoded using base-36 values:

- The least significant bit gives the ending pattern: `0` for `//`, `1` for `\\`.
- All other bits give the number of spaces before the ending pattern.

Everything can be encoded this way with a single base-36 digit except the last line which consists of 30 spaces followed by `\\`, leading to 30*2+1 = 61 = `1p` in base-36. This `p` should be interpreted as 12 spaces followed by `\\` but this pattern doesn't appear anywhere. So, we can simply handle this special case at the cost of 2 extra bytes in the regular expression: `/.p?/`.

---

## First version, 186 bytes

*NB: This one was submitted prior to the logo update.*

```js
let f =

_=>[...`WALKER'S`].reduce((s,c)=>(x=s.split(c)).join(x.pop()),`E
 ELSRE
'LK'
 'LRWLR
WSKS'SK
S ESRLESR
S'KL'K
S 'RKEWR
LEAK'WA
L AKWW
SKERS'RE
L 'ALEA'
LLLS'S    '  ER  AE\\\\KSALSSA//WSE`)

O.innerText = f()
```

```html
<pre id=O>
```

Comment: Nicely golfed. Took a stab at this myself before checking the answers; ended up with something similar to your 172 byte version.

Answer (score 7):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 579 bytes

```
+++++++++[>+>+++++>+++>++++++++++<<<<-]>+>++>+++++>++..<<<.>>.>..<..............<..>>..<..<<.>>..>..<............<..>..>..<............<..<.>>...>..<..........<..>....>..<..........<..<.>>....>..<........<..>......>..<........<..<.>>.....>..<......<..>........>..<......<..<.>>......>..<....<..>..........>..<....<..<.>>.......>..<..<..>....<..>>..<....>..<..<..<.>>........>..<<..>....<..>..>..<....>..<<..<.>>.........<..>....<..>....>..<....>..<<<.>>........<..>>..<..<..>......>..<..<..>>..<<<.>>...........>..<<..>........>..<<..>..>..<<<.>>..............................>..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRCoAgDEU/KNoXyH4keqggiKCHoO9fQzfdphcEd@5BZPu7Xc/5HTfRpFlwwnxBOZLEmddc1h6AISAC8g1ceMRCi9EpKaMBLXpoij2gYrtC5Y6qbHhzA61uxVZ1tKlC1WxLMI2xM7Rye1YaK4M3g2tNs/ywCm2cHj7i55E9CNdEPw)

Generates the constants `47 92 32 10` in memory, then selects and outputs them as appropriate.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure this can be golfed down, especially that last part

Comment: @StanStrum Feel free to give it a shot. I tried but couldn't find any nice way to express it, especially given BF's verbosity in conditionals.

Answer (score 6):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 38 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
6«╝5╚@┼╬⁷7«8ž'⁸3L╚ž92L╚╬5L«26«╝╬5:21╬5
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=NiVBQiV1MjU1RDUldTI1NUFAJXUyNTNDJXUyNTZDJXUyMDc3NyVBQjgldTAxN0UlMjcldTIwNzgzTCV1MjU1QSV1MDE3RTkyTCV1MjU1QSV1MjU2QzVMJUFCMjYlQUIldTI1NUQldTI1NkM1JTNBMjEldTI1NkM1)

Comment: Now we're waiting for Charcoal :P

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder if it doesn't beat me, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>77</s> 76 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 75cf c109 8000 0c43 d17b a6c8 0659 28fb  u......C.{...Y(.
0000010: cf21 05cb a782 3de9 4b5a b495 5b9f 4946  .!....=.KZ..[.IF
0000020: 870f dac3 f8ea 5704 51b9 2284 c611 0114  ......W.Q.".....
0000030: 9029 f09e ec67 2362 21e1 075e 2136 29b9  .)...g#b!..^!6).
0000040: 08b9 bf97 8939 cf33 ebbf d33e            .....9.3...>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY8/SwRBDMV7P8U7bbwmzEzmX4SzEQSxshIVhM3szDVabnUffo27Fr4iJIT3e4kuql/9vHyvq9t1h5LaQPNOUG2Ga5Ex@6KYcqtwOQlCHQostOmBLlbfbulqA3hDtBE8XGrmKTWA5y6ImiZolISkMhAlZoAOv4QTPb8TfdDT444IhqjFDcxTY4zaJ6TiIpJXyw41omVvAd5HQ2x6pRe63rodwYYQFwTDSUdvuSBwDgi@m7Gkbh1nBDEi6Gi@843aMZ@HfPxDREO4ansdUlCFxf5iRle1y5g7/mmLFmKr9@v6Aw)

Bubblegum threshold. :P

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 166 bytes

```
/-/!#//,/%"//'/%#//&/!!//%/  //#/\\\/\\\///"/\\\\\\\\//!/%%/"
 "&!'"%
,&-,&-
% "&'!"&'
!"&#!,&#
! "!'&"!'
!,-&,-
!% "'-"!"'
&"#-,!"#
& #-!"!"
&#"'!,'"
&% "#&"#,
&&&!,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDkMxCEN3ThGDgAXkC2XpUKlDt9xfKf2IB8b4fF/n8z73sgkji65k0kcHAdK5Fmncez@Q@t9PkaA7VZYGUl0qelp87sQgMwwVJliKjEFQHdWCCWUrNCXUuqAmsawxloRponLEpGz@JRGBuvcH)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 377 bytes

```c
char*r="2\\01 2\\14 2/2\\02 2\\12 2/2 2\\12 2/03 2\\10 2/4 2\\10 2/04 2\\8 2/6 2\\8 2/05 2\\6 2/8 2\\6 2/06 2\\4 2/10 2\\4 2/07 2\\2 2/4 2/2\\4 2\\2 2/08 2\\2/4 2/2 2\\4 2\\2/09 2/4 2/4 2\\4 2\\08 2/2\\2 2/6 2\\2 2/2\\011 2\\2/8 2\\2/2 2\\030 2\\";char d[9];main(i){do{if(*r==48)puts(""),r++;for(i=0;isdigit(*r);d[i++]=*r++);for(d[i]=0,i=atoi(d);i--;putchar(*r));}while(*r++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBBjoMwDEWvglglpSgmZTpUUU7SskBk2lqaGSpK1QXi7NR2gE30vu3/LafNb207z@296Xe9T@3lAkVCb1Em1rCyoiyrjeAgCITlRiBYER1XgC8mkqZaAaTJ4WyKBN9MNqaZWIwaxLfUk61j4LQMl1uRR81iO65@OaeIniVKYuAgy1PHdyfhfKrdX4P/CvUYuhGviv7Cl5V@vIanSlO977PMXbteoQeHz4A3HGhGu3DGLKv9jvpaBqhQe9ijb4YOVdAO89xRDC9ih3bT@46/Pypapnn@AA)

Comment: [356 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY/RbsIwDEXf9xVVJqGEaJoTAiuK8gf7AqAPVdOCpa1FodMeEPv1Lm7Nk8917rWd5u3cNNP0GtsO@7Y4iMKeTuJlncKnyARGHIRxhX0nYUlYEk@ADRFkck8AojLDjitsM@wylFyBXmimAQb4yEDzeJNjCRThLllnBXs2Om5BuaQsL7V8rjGzf5lBedjkhb651KmIx33l0X/X2Et1j8O9G5JMOuSPB1euVtef8SaFUD4esQp4i3jGUa7T3NC6ykatlacUhr96HFBG5bVGf03Yj51MSvnH7wW/WrlYH9P0Dw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 197 bytes

```python
print''.join(i>'/'and(i<'2'and['/','\\'][int(i)]*2or' '*int(i))or i for i in"""1
 19501
2193021
319 0419 0
41806180
51608160
61409 140
71204014120
8104021410
90404141
8012061201
921081021
99931""")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY09DsIwDIV3nyLq4hYhsN00xBLiIm0HJIQIQ1JVXTh9cGF4z9@T/5bP9ipZal3WlDfE07uk3KYbnvGeH226ouwwWj7iNOE82libuvkgZUWHh3/syuqSe/485aZpGBzrQAzC2pMw9KyO/G7gOVIwwcCBogkCe1JnBhcW8sTeCkQ2FGMCNfJGEMk6wcSgwra931bVnu1pV@sX)

Uses the logic from the JS answer.

Comment: [191 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY0xDsIwDEV3nyLq4rQDtd00xBLiIpQBCSHCkFRVF04fXIb//WT72@t3f9cira1bLjvi6VNz8fmKIz7K0@cLygE4LgverE14H6Ru6HCwfZ/7vm4uu9ffc@m6jsGxzsQgrBMJw8TqKBwGgRNFE8wcKZkgciB1ZnBmoUAcrEBiQzEmUKNgBIlsEk0MKmzp47aqTmxP@9Z@ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>161</s> 160 bytes

```
foldr(\a->(++(' '<$[1..fromEnum a-last(96:[64|a<'`'])])++last("\\\\":["//"|a<'`'])))""<$>words"` `Na LbLb JdJc HfHd FhFe DjDf Bd`DBg @dbD@h ddDI `BfB`H b@h@k ~"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcndCoIwAIbhW/kYwhRJCUIoLIassLBOOtRoszkt/0KNTqJbtwh6D5@3kH2ZVdU45kvdVqozEzlZmbZtUlDfiKeOo7u2XjePGnJSyX4w594i9mYv6VNBT9bJsu0fk@QbWcTEdcl/WhYhvrF6tp3qiYA4SERplGKndheEOlTYFJsM/MY1AiV4kIOplLMCSvEtRKADESJlBSvxJmMtrw2WqOV9f8b9MRyHLmqQjx8)

Spaces before `\\` are encoded as lowercase letters and before `//` as uppercase letters where the number of spaces is the ASCII value minus 96 (or 64). Zero spaces is `` ` `` / `@`. The Spaces of each line are stored in reverse order, because the are consumes by a right-fold.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 51 bytes

```
Ｐ↘¹²→↘¹²↑Ｐ↗⁵→↗⁵↓Ｐ↘⁵→↘⁵↑Ｐ↗χ→↗χＭ¹¹↓Ｍ⁵←Ｐ↖¹²←↖¹²↓Ｐ↙χ←↙χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9ng2P2mYc2nlo06O2SXDWRLDw9EeNW8GiEMZkiFqYIIQBVXm@HaLwfPv7PWuBZuwEK18LVjIBrGQaxOQJcBbEuJkgnRPA9P//AA)

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
Ｐ↘χ→↘χ↑Ｐ↗⁵→↗⁵Ｍ⁵↑←Ｐ↙χ←↙χＭχ↗‖ＭＭ¹⁸←Ｐ↖²←↖²Ｊ²⁷¦⁹Ｐ↘²→↘²¦
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9ng2P2macb3/UNglKTwQLTX/UuBUsBmK837MWzJ34qG0CWHYmSOEEMA2UA3GmP2qYBmQC0aGdjxp3wBROO7QJrBBIv9@zCshp3H5o2aPGnRBrQZKTwPShZf//AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>50</s> 31 bytes

```
Ｆ²«↘¹²↗↗⁵↘↘⁵↗↗⁹Ｍχ↓Ｍ⁴←↖¹²↙↙χＪ¹¦⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0hToZpLAQgCijLzSjSsXPLL84Iy0zNKdBQMjTTBMr75ZakaVqEFYGFNZMVQMR0FU2SVcCM0cRhsSrS5lkgqDQ10FMCmIImZAIV8UtPQdYOE0N0P0omhFCYIVGwAkfAqzS0Iydcw1FEACtT@//9ft@y/bnEOAA) Link is to verbose version.

I tried. (Also, I will point out that I did this completely on my own, even if it looks somewhat similar to the other one. [Shiz, I did it again. This is still different, by the way. :P])

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 122 bytes (121 chars)

```cs
_=>@"
A
9;13) +!(# 0$(	-) 
4	(	€".SelectMany(j=>(j%2>0?"//":@"\\").PadLeft(j/4)+(j%4>1?"\n":""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5@UlZpcouPpmleam1qUmJSTapOckVhkZ5dm@z/e1s5BiYvHkUvAUsBaxFDCWEJTQVtGUUNZQdJAWkVQkkNCWINTUkCCW1dSQkqTQ1BBkMuEU4NT6FCDkl5wag7QXN/EvEqNLFs7jSxVIzsDeyV9fSUrB6WYGCVNvYDEFJ/UtBKNLH0TTW2gvImdob1STJ6SlZKSpuZ/a67wosySVI3ikqLMvHQ95/y85MQSjTQNY01NTev/AA)

## Explanation

Each part of the logo is just 0+ spaces with either a `\\` or a `//` at the end, plus maybe a newline. There are [52](https://regex101.com/r/FshY2m/1) of these. We then encode each segment into a character:

- Take the number of spaces in each segment, then add 2 to that number.
- Bit shift the number to the left 2 times.
- If the segment ends with `//`, bit-wise OR the number by one.
- If the segment ends with a newline, bit-wise OR the number by two.
- Take the number, and cast it into a char.
- Repeat for each segment.

Here are all of the 52 segments and the numeric value they encode into:

```cs
10,12,65,10,16,57,16,59,20,49,24,51,24,41,32,43,28,33,40,35,32,25,48,27,36,17,25,8,24,19,40,9,25,16,24,11,45,25,24,26,41,8,17,32,17,10,52,9,40,9,18,128
```

Comment: `j>>2` -> `j/4`

Comment: [124](https://tio.run/##Jc69C4JAGIBxtAathrMajBquN6I7srSPpQ@vIAqaG1oOoo4zlDpBjfrvLWx9hh@PSEciDfPDS4l1fIukyJzjXr2eMrneHnKdZkmo7owFfn7xGejlhW5MjFmNoiHq2r1mC7dtizQ6psU9VMWaZaBS30L1LvdM29QdDWtcfWB8ko8fTSKfKfnGp0IlAzxwIndOhyTqT5m3AdeF5RY4hyLN2WQDXMESgNJ8VTknYSbJ/2i8i5W4ZiQgM0rpKv8C). also i think you can put the null-bytes in if you hand-craft the URL

Comment: in the explanation: bitshift _left_, not right. also list of strings is only if you return each line as its own string... you'll need the `string.Concat` here for it to be valid...

Comment: [close](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5@UlZpcolNcUpSZl26XZvs/3tYOwtFzzs9LTizRUGJisWTiMOQw5tEU0BZQlFAWkVSQlhDUEJbhFIwxEOBWYBTkEGBWFRQQUowx4JTgZNJhVGCMyatQ0gtOzQGarZFla5eXWq4QDDZVQ11BXSdL30RTGygWHVvtoBQTo6SjpK@vpANicoHZMXlKtdFZqiaxmpr/rbnCizJLUjXSNIw1Na3/AwA), this is 143 whereas normal is 141

Comment: @ASCII-only I am pretty sure returning a list of strings like this is allowed, but I'll add another solution just in case. However, is this valid: https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5@UlZpcouPpmleam1qUmJSTalNcUpSZlx4da2eXZvs/3tZOiYnFkonDkMOYR1NAW0BRQllEUkFaQlBDWIZTMMZAgFuBUZBDgFlVUEBIMcaAU4KTSYdRgTEmr0JJLzg1B2i4RpatnUZearlCMNhgDXUFdZ0sfRNNbY0sVSM7A3slfX0lKwelmBglsJCJnaG9UkyekpWSkqamXnBBTmaJBoj535orvCizJFUD4j495/y85MQSjTQNY02YRcm2dqiSyZpAYP0fAA

Comment: Check the meta rules for input/output, [submissions may use a list of strings instead of _multiline_ strings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17095/39244). anything else is _not_ allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>221</s> 220 bytes

```powershell
$ofs=''
"b
 b$(' '*14)/b
$((2..6|%{' '*$_+"b$(($a=' '*(14-++$i*2)))/$(' '*$i*2)b$a/`n"}))   4b  /4/b4b  /
44b/4/  b4b/
44 /4/4b4b
44/b  /4  b  /b
44   b/44b/  b
$(' '*30)b"-replace4,'    '-replace'/','//'-replace'b','\\'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsIwEITveYolRDbp39oavPVNCtqViEKxpT14UJ89blrE08y3M7PT@AzzcgvDEKMZr0uLqDQrYGMRMKu9I1bG2qaqju/dK93MKdcSW9O3CW3tyzw396xxztE2W4lNT@eH/jgHAJ4ByBOvqrxnAQDBBCnx4sXS2pNEJLFMpSo1UbU9P@wd63IO09Bfgi9QKoA/RsICif7Mwl2HMX4B)

Fairly naïve approach (*and 50 bytes worse than the JS answer, cringe*). Anyone know of a way to do multiple `-replace`s in PowerShell?

*-1 byte thanks to Veskah.*

Comment: [If you swap `\\` to any other character, you can save escaping it in the replace statement for a byte.](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsIwEITveYolRDbp39oavPVNCtqViEKxpT14UJ89blrE08y3M7PT@AzzcgvDEKMZr0uLqDQrYGMRMKu9I1bG2qaqju/dK93MKdcSW9O3CW3tyzw396xxztE2W4lNT@eH/jgHAJ4ByBOvqrxnAQDBBCnx4sXS2pNEJLFMpSo1UbU9P@wd63IO09Bfgi9QKoA/RsICif7Mwl2HMX4B "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Veskah Simple byte savings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 65 bytes

```
“<fṭY2Ẹ<ƭẹ£ʋ¥¹)Œ<Ẓ⁹ḣ⁶ıĠ\ṃṛ?04|ẏḌẉƙ+’b36⁶ẋ“ÇỴ$ñ⁵FḄ’Bị⁾\/¤ẋ€2¤żFs36
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AY0Acv9qZWxsef//4oCcPGbhua1ZMuG6uDzGreG6ucKjyovCpcK5KcWSPOG6kuKBueG4o@KBtsSxxKBc4bmD4bmbPzA0fOG6j@G4jOG6icaZK@KAmWIzNuKBtuG6i@KAnMOH4bu0JMOx4oG1RuG4hOKAmULhu4vigb5cL8Kk4bqL4oKsMsKkxbxGczM2/8KiWf8)

Returns a list of characters. TIO link has a footer to print on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 186 bytes:

Both versions require PHP 5.5 or later.

Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/579959d3865b656e2e0251beb67c2a2bdeb550d5)

---

space compression gives the shortest alternative:

(double backslash mapped to `0`, double slash to `f`, sapces compressed to digits)

```php
while(~$c="0
1077f0
2066f2066f
3055f4055f
408f608f
506f806f
604f5504f
702f4f0402f
80f4f2040f
9f4f4040
8f02f602f0
560f80f20
87870"[$i++])echo+$c?str_pad("",$c):strtr($c,["\\\\",f=>"//"]);
```

PHP 7.1 yields warnings; replace `+$c` with `$c>0` to fix.

---

base 64 encoded bitmap (**187 bytes**):

(mapped space to `00`, newline to `01`, double backslash to `10` and double slash to `11`,
then concatenated 3 "pixels" each to one character,
prepended `1` and converted from binary to ASCII)

```php
for(;$c=ord("d`@@@@yB@@@@p`@@@M@`@@C@H@@@t@`@@p@H@@M@B@@p@@`@M@@`C@@@H@t@@`pC`BCP@@l@p`Bt@@C@L@`BP@@xL@BCd@@@K@@Bpd@@@@@@@@@B"
[$i++]);)for($b=6;$b;)echo[" ","
","\\\\","//"][3&$c>>$b-=2];
```

(first linebreak for reading convenience; the other one is essential)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 74 bytes

```
00000000: 758c 4b11 0400 0885 eea6 a081 85e8 9f63  u.K............c
00000010: 4fb2 7f4f 0e30 4f07 e5ed 7615 8613 e16f  O..O.0O...v....o
00000020: 321c ab89 d484 4a22 2591 8a48 45a0 2052  2.....J"%..HE. R
00000030: 809e dfd5 481e 3d0d 7a24 4d96 bc43 b2fd  ....H.=.z$M..C..
00000040: 96d3 cdbf fff9 7fa7 f300                 ..........
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XdDNSgUxDAXgvU9xEN2GNE07qeBKhIsiF3yDdtq4UVxdF7782KsDimcRyObLTzu19jpeTm/bxntusCRboS0EsDKDzRLGqBmVLcDSMBTPETjRI/3JevEjhGmoN8Hi6uAReba8YKTRseSQYDlEjJAdOBIdiWelj7PxvhsyjShhRW1W0NUUWkUgqcwVqho0VYZwEkC@xz9cXhMd7gnPuxGnYVwGuvcEtTAQO88Vqkytl4y2akQT78BZONAtfV49Ed0R7YZOo@QesfbmcPcyr6oLPM7P/M/vK7btCw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 180 bytes

```python
print''.join(c<'3'and'\\/\n\\/'[int(c)::3]or' '*(int(c,36)-2)for c in'0230g104240e140e1250c160c1260a180a127081a08128061c0612904161060412a0161406012b16160602a1041804102d01a01402w0')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxLDsIwDESv0p0bxMd2QggVN6EsQsqnLJKqqoQ4fRhYPPvJo/H0WZ4la63TPOaFaPsqY27TiSzFPFDf7/qMQWekbTJdZy9lpoZW7f@wtt5s1NzL3KRmzMRq@SHs1PFNfuiek3ignqMEoAcOEoEG9pKAHtmJF/ZYGhnq4KJXmIdpxEd0nbAOjC5yfTOZWr8)

The encoding is base 36:

```python
0 => \\
1 => //
2 => \n
```

and otherwise,

```python
n => (n-2) spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>144</s> <s>140</s> 139 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

Each character in the string encodes a number of spaces to use before a certain string. If it's a lower-case letter (or a backtick), then the string is "\", and if upper-case or @, it's "//". A space signifies a newline.

```c
f(c,i){for(i=0;c="` aN` bLbL cJdJ dHfH eFhF fDjD gBD`dB h@Dbd@ IDdd H`BfB` k@h@b ~"[i++];)printf("%*s",c%32+2,c<33?"\n":c<96?"//":"\\\\");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrdCoIwFADg63yKwwFhS6NQCPIHRUZYSC@QwdxZ0xVZWHdir2591x@tWqJ5Nox8y0fzHJhNNzGlKKE5SVCVqoCO@gi6NCVc990ejLgJaAshdQFdLpTO4SC0hlIWppBwz7tcwRfP1vMuMX8Ntv8Yhu7yjT65YeAFPiVhmGHdY0TJbpvheo0R1n/I42n@f3g0tmfcGZ2FYTx2pvkH)